# Normal form of a reducible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, matrix-decomposition, convention

If a matrix $A$ is reducible, it is always possible to find a permutation matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{\intercal}$ has the block triangular form
$$
PAP^{\intercal}=\begin{pmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12} & \cdots & A_{1n}\\
 & A_{22} & \cdots & A_{2n}\\
 &  & \ddots & \vdots\\
 &  &  & A_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where each matrix $A_{ii}$ on the diagonal is either irreducible or a $1\times1$ zero matrix.

In the book Matrix Iterative Analysis, Richard S. Varga refers to this as a *normal form* of a matrix. However, the name normal form is not particularly telling, as there are various forms referred to as normal (i.e., Jordan normal form, Smith normal form, etc.). Is there a better name for $PAP^{\intercal}$ that is standard in the literature?

Comment: I like Folded matrix. Like a discrete squared "sheet of points" folded in half